# How to do in place scale down of App Service Premium plan to take advantage of Reserved Instance?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

As per my knowledge, Azure VM allows user to do in-place scaling up and down with Reserved Instance (RI) offer (1/2/3 yrs).

If I have an App Service with Premium plan, and Azure Advisor service gives me recommendation to use RI, how do I use the reserved instance offer for 1/2/3 years? Can I just scale down App Service plan to availa the new pricing from App service left navigation panel and just select the new plan or same plan with RI offer? Because I am unable to do this in-place scaling down to use RI for my existing App Service plan in my Dev/Test or Prod environments.

Or do I have to recreate my App Service plan infrastructure from scratch again to use RI offer of Premium or Isolated plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to know about Reserved Instances in Azure is that

> The reserved instance pricing applies to the applicable instances in
> your subscription, up to the number of instances that you reserve. The
> reserved instances are a billing matter and are not tied to specific
> compute instances

[App Service RI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-manage-costs)

So if you reserve 2 instances, then each billing period will have the cost of up to 2 instances deducted.  If you are running 3 matching instances, the cost for 2 will be deducted.  If you are running 1 matching instance, the cost for 1 will be deducted.

Comment: Thanks and understood. But what is the way to get this deduction or discount if my App Service plan is created without RI and I want to avail the RI benefit? Do I create new App Service Plan with RI and migrate existing instance to the new one or do inplace update (scale up/down) of App Service Plan to availe the RI pricing on existing App Service plan?

Comment: You don't apply the RI to a particular instance.  It doesn't matter if the ASP is new or existing, so long as it matches the RI.